# Placing logout button in menu-less application

Tags: user-expectation, mobile-application, logout

This particular application does not have a side menu, bottom navigation or a Profile/Account page. Although it requires the user to **Sign In** to proceed.

> **NOTE**: This is a front-facing application where the user can login to view details and actions from his/her account. That is the reason why it doesn't have any other account-related actions

Usually, the logout/sign out option goes in the side navigation pane or in the account page.

One possible option here is to **place the Logout option inside an Ellipses dropdown on the right-top corner of the title bar**

### Q: Is this the best approach given that in some screens, there might be another action icon present on the right side?

Comment: If you have a sign-in then surely you *need* some sort of account management (change password, change email, etc)?

Comment: @AndrewMartin -  This is a client-side action application where all the account management is done by a system admin (yes, including use-cases like password reset). Not the best idea, but I have no control over as it is a legacy application undergoing a UI refresh

Comment: You say the admin does a password reset, how does the client request it?

Comment: It's a front-facing application that shows the user details about their account. The account management isn't present here. The password reset workflow is present in the full-fledged portal that allows the user to request a password reset

Comment: How on earth do they get into the application?

Comment: @DarrylGodden - They sign in using their account credentials

Comment: One page app? There's nowhere to go from here?

Comment: @UXfrom12 - I never said that it was a single page app. The screenshot was a reference to where actions are placed on the top-nav. I have removed it now because I feel like people are getting side-tracked by it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62963/discussion-between-uxfrom12-and-shreyas-tripathy).

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you choose, you'll implicitly be adding the 'menu' that this app has been missing.  Users will begin to click it for all of their other confusions and needs.

If you can / if not already present, add an interaction monitor of some kind - so that you can see how many people go to the menu, but do not logout.  This can be used as a kind of (or part of) a 'frustration measure'.

These things will help make and win the case that the app, however legacy, needs some basic items in a menu, to rescue the few worse-cases of the customer experience - which are doubtlessly hurting the image of the product already.

---

And, Yes, a three-dot menu is a as good of a solution as any, including a 'burger' menu, down arrow/carat, two/three arrows, etc.

Even just an `X`, since it denotes 'closing', and will make sense with a subsequent modal to confirm Logout. This limits your options to make improvements in the UX, but sadly I'm guessing it'll work the best.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, the menu-like dropdown would the right location to place the logout button.*

You don't have to go far to see an example implementation. Just click the top right button on this website and you'll find an option to logout right below it.